# Rules for <body> in external CSS not being applied

Tags: html, css

It seems that my external style sheet is not working for the body part. Here’s my code:

**all.css:**

```
body {
    background: url(../texture1.jpg);
    background-size: 600px 500px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h3 id="h3">
            <a class="a" href="home.php"><div id="active" style="left:20px;"><center>Work Load</div></a></br>
            <a class="a" href="assign.php"><div class="div" style="left:210px"><center>Assign Employee</div></a></br>
            <a class="a" href="accounts.php"><div class="div" style="left:400px"><center>Accounts</div></a>
        </h3>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: look for any error on the href atribute

Comment: You can’t have multiple elements with the same `id`. Also, where’s `texture1.jpg`? Open your browser’s development tools; check the network panel for problems loading the image or the stylesheet, then use a DOM inspector of some sort to determine whether the rules are being applied correctly.

Comment: I believe he meant that the CSS code was his "all.css" file.

Comment: ../texture1.jpg should be in quotes `'../texture1.jpg'` ... Are you sure that the path to that image is correct?

Comment: @JRulle: Quotes aren’t necessary.

Comment: thanks.. i tried ..but no progress.. still not workin :(

Comment: Is it in the right directory?

Comment: yes.. i tried it in the internal , and it works..but not working in external..

Comment: You have conflicting rules. Try changing `background` to `background-image`. And make dead sure it's pointing to the right directory. Which errors are you getting on the page? Does it 404 the image?

Comment: Noe that paths are relative to the document the CSS is in. If your CSS file is in a diferent directory to yout HTML file that will explain the problem. Use a root relative path for your urls in stylesheets.

Comment: there's no error..but the image does not appear @nix

Comment: What I mean is: have you debugged the output? Open up the developer tool in your browser, and find out which rules are being applied to body. It's likely something to do with your cascade or your path.

Comment: my browser is chrome.. how can i do that @nix??

Comment: Press f12 to bring up developer tools. The use the "network" tab to see if elements are being downloaded.

Comment: F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I opens up the dev tool in Chrome – or right click an element and choose "inspect". Then, in the HTML view, highlight the body tag. On the left, you will see which rules are being applied, and in which order. Also do what @JonP describes. This should help you on your way to solve your problem, and debug other problems in the future.

Comment: The network tab should list all the ressources that your page tries to download (request). Your texture1.jpg should be there somewhere. It will also return a status code. 404 means it can't find the image – your path is likely wrong. 200 means everything is OK, and the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I guess i just have to use internal styles.. there's no problem that way

Answer (score 1):

You have several flaws in your HTML code:

- `<style></style>` - Empty style blocks, not really an issue
- `<center>` tags don't seem to have a closing tag. This tag is deprecated, and you should consider using the CSS style `text-align: center` instead.
- `id="div"` - Having multiple ID's with the same value is not recommended because it can have unexplained results. The purpose of these is make them unique.
- `</div>` inside `<a>` tags - In HTML4, having block-level elements inside inline elements was not allowed. This has changed in HTML5, keep aware.
- `style="left:###px"` - Having 'left' as a style property does nothing by itself. That element needs to have the associated `position` property set too, whether it's set to "relative", "absolute", "fixed", or even "static"

Fixing these issues are probably your top priority, because the structure of your page is messed up beyond repair that the browser doesn't render your (correct) CSS properly.

Also, make sure that your "texture1.jpg" is in the **parent** directory of **all.css**, which seems to be one directory above your **home.php** file. Try removing the "**../**", and you should be good if it's all in the same directory.

To be a little more elaborate, this is how your application sees your folder structure:

```
???
|--public_html          <--- Root HTML directory
|    |-- all.css        <--- CSS File you provided
|    |-- home.php       <--- HTML file you provided
|    |-- assign.php
|    +-- accounts.php
+--picture1.jpg         <--- Picture file? CSS/HTML file cannot access above public_html
```

If by your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418955/rules-for-body-in-external-css-not-being-applied/23419089?noredirect=1#comment35888675_23419089) you say it's in the same as the HTML file, then inside `all.css`, change the line to just `url('picture1.jpg')`.

---

As a rare favor, I'll see if I can fix everything from the information you've provided and all 3 files (CSS, HTML, JPG) are in the same directory. You don't seem to understand the concept of how [classes and IDs](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/) work together.

**home.php** HTML (complete):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h3>
            <a class="active" href="home.php">Work Load</a><br />
            <a href="assign.php">Assign Employee</a><br />
            <a href="accounts.php">Accounts</a>
        </h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**all.css** CSS (with added styles, some sample):

```
body {
    background: url('texture1.jpg');
    background-size: 600px 500px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
#main {
    background-color: lightpink;
}   
.active {
    color: green;
}
h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I've created a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Djn7w/) with this info and I hope you can use it as a learning lesson to see how [selectors work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) in CSS and how it correlates to your HTML structure.

Comment: the close div tag was for the div tag after the body

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific. There's `div` tags before your `</a>` tags for each link.

Comment: i tried removing "../" still not working @laughdonor

Comment: Well where exactly is your image file located in relation to your CSS file?

Comment: and by the way,, all that have the same id have the same properties.. do i have to separate them?? then i guess it will make my code longer

Comment: If you have multiple elements with the same styles, then [use classes](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/). Is your CSS file in the same directory as your HTML file? Also, I updated my answer.

Comment: i used class.. and it got worse .. the properties are not appearing anymore

Comment: Which properties are you referring to?

Comment: those properties for the divs

Comment: The styles? Sorry, you need to be specific.

Comment: I guess i just have to use internal styles.. there's no problem that way

Comment: No, it's doable, we just need to understand the scenario. I'll update my answer with all the detailed corrections.

Answer (score 0):

just add 
{}
before body, it worked for me

Comment: {}
body {
    background: url(../texture1.jpg);
    background-size: 600px 500px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}